# ACF Wordpress display an image shortcode problem

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display an image on the homepage using a shortcode and ACF.

The problem I am having is that the code is fetching the data for the correct post, but it is displaying a line of text of the image address, rather than an image. When I view the page source it appears the the img tag is not working.

This is the code I have. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```php
function grab_home_image_init(){
    add_shortcode( 'grab_home_image', 'grab_home_image_cb' );
}
add_action('init', 'grab_home_image_init');


function grab_home_image_cb() { 

        extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'project',
            ),
            $atts,
            'grab_home_image'
        ) );

    $args = array (
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'numberposts' => $numberposts, 
    );

    $ML_home_image = get_posts( $args );

    if( ! empty( $ML_home_image ) ){
        foreach ( $ML_home_image as $p ){
            $output = '<img src="' . the_field('main_image',$p->ID) . '">';
        }
    }
    return $output ?? '<strong>Error</strong>';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using get_field instead of the_field?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you